# Phone switches to watch interface when put against a specific side of my laptop

Tags: lg-g2, smart-cover

Not a very annoying bug, but quite mysterious:

I noticed that when I put my LG G2 (running v4.4.2, with NFC turned off) against the top left edge of the lid of my laptop (ASUS Zenbook UX303LN running Linux Mint), whether closed or open, so that the phone's power button ([on the back on LG G2](http://www.lg.com/au/images/pressrelease/G2_Black_Basic%20%287%29.jpg)) is aligned with the edge, my phone magically switches its interface into a tiny watch screen, in which I can unlock the screen (difficultly), switch watch designs, view the weather forecast and play music. As soon as I take the phone out of that spot, the regular interface comes back.

I would be glad if someone could tell me he could reproduce it, and was wondering if anybody had witnessed such an odd behaviour and/or could explain it?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I 99% believe it's similar to [tag:smart-cover], where magnets on some covers are used to detect if the covers are closed/opened.... which mean there's a magnetic field near the lid of your laptop.

Comment: You may be right. Just asked a friend of mine who has a zenbook and on his phone (Galaxy Note 2), it locks his screen

Comment: And there does seem to be a magnet on the left side of the lid (and not the right side, for some reason) to keep the laptop closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tiny watch screen is a feature of LG G2 named QuickWindow when put on a smart cover (a cover that uses magnets to detect if it's closed or opened).

[image: LG G2 smart cover]

<sup>(LG G2 showing tiny watch when put on smart cover)</sup>

That indicates there's a magnet field on a particular spot on ASUS Zenbook, and LG G2 reacts to that on a very specific position. (As already confirmed by OP, there's a magnet on the left side of the lid to keep the laptop closed)