# Tilting Huawei Ascend Mate 2 just right displays a gray screen with a clock

Tags: huawei

I can be in a game or any other up, but when I tilt my phone back a little to avoid glare, this notification thing comes up with a clock. If I hold it just right and scroll right it shows me the weather and the status of my internet, data, bluetooth and GPS.

It is really annoying and I have no idea how to stop it from happening. I am trying to snap a screenshot of this and if I manage to, I will upload it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a cover, or near a magnet? Seems an issue related to [tag:smart-cover] (example: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109346/phone-switches-to-watch-interface-when-put-against-a-specific-side-of-my-laptop)... does the notification look like [this](http://www.amazon.com/HUAWEI-Ascend-including-MT2-L03-Visual/dp/B00KHFOCMA)?